# Change img url in css file

Tags: c#, css, url, model

```
.def_img {background-image:url(../img/def_bg.jpg);}
```

this code in my theme.css file. I want to change this code with c#. like this;

```
.def_img {background-image:url(../@Model.Url);}
```

How can I change image url in css file with sql

Comment: Did you try anything yet?

Answer (score 1):

If you include the css in your .cshtml you can modify it with Razor. I don't think you can use SQL to modify it.

**layout.cshtml**

```
<head>
@if (IsSectionDefined("Style"))
{
  @RenderSection("Style");
}
</head>
...
```

**page.cshtml**

```
@model MyModel
@{        
  Layout = "layout.cshtml";
}
@section Style
{
  <style type="text/css">        
    .def_img {background-image:url(../@Model.Url);}
  </style>
}
...
```